# Как заполнить таблицу интервалом дат?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица формата

| id | Минимум | Максимум |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 01.01.2000 | 03.03.2000 |
| 02 | 02.02.2001 | 11.05.2001 |

Необходимо сделать таблицу со списком дат с шагом в месяц для каждого id от минимального к максимальному. И чтобы даты были последним днём месяца.
По типу:

| id | Дата |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | 31.01.2000 |
| 01 | 28.02.2000 |
| 01 | 31.03.2000 |
| 02 | 28.02.2001 |
| 02 | 31.03.2001 |
| 02 | 30.04.2001 |
| 02 | 31.05.2001 |

что-то по типу цикла:
для каждого id добавить дату с шагом 1 месяц, пока дата меньше, чем максимум

мой неработающий код:

```
WITH t AS(
select id, EOMONTH(Минимум) AS min_v, Минимум, Максимум
from my_table
UNION ALL
SELECT id, EOMONTH(DATEADD(m, 1, d)), Минимум, Максимум
FROM t
WHERE EOMONTH(Минимум) <= Максимум)
```

пишет ошибку "adding a value to a 'date' column caused an overflow"

Comment: у вас в примере даты есть больше чем максимум.

Comment: в целом тут про рекурсивные CTE

Comment: @teran месяц - всегда последней датой. в 01 - с января по март (3 месяца), в 02 с февраля по май (4 месяца)

Comment: @teran и как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я немного поправлю Ваш код. Иначе получается бесконечная рекурсия или переполнение, что раньше.

```
WITH t AS(
select id, EOMONTH(Минимум) AS d, Минимум, Максимум
from my_table
UNION ALL
SELECT id, EOMONTH(DATEADD(m, 1, d)), Минимум, Максимум
FROM t
WHERE EOMONTH(d) < Максимум)
```

Условие нужно `WHERE EOMONTH(d) < Максимум)` поскольку здесь в сравнении `d` - от предыдущей итерации.

Вот еще вариант, практически такой же:

```
create table test (id int,[Минимум] date,[Максимум] date);
insert into test values
 (01,'2000.01.01','2000.03.03')
,(02,'2001.02.02','2001.05.31')
;
with r as(
select id, eomonth([Минимум]) [Дата],eomonth([Максимум]) [МаксДата]
from test
union all
select id, eomonth(dateadd(m,1,[Дата])), [МаксДата]
from r 
where eomonth(dateadd(m,1,[Дата]))<= [МаксДата]
)
```

Comment: Всё работает. Спасибо